# Having transition/ animated effect when making menu visible in action bar

Tags: android

Currently, I have a menu in action bar, which I will make it visible during run-time.

```
public void setShareMenuVisible(final boolean visible) {
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (shareMenu != null) {
                shareMenu.setVisible(visible);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:visible="false"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
        android:title="@string/menu_about"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>   
</menu>
```

---

However, `shareMenu.setVisible(true)` is not attractive enough. I would like the menu be either, transits animated from top of the screen to its current location, or use alpha animation to appear on its current location.

[image]

I know Android supports animation as the following tutorial described. (Use `View.startAnimation()`)

http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-1/

However, `Menu` are not `View`. How is it possible for me to have animation effect on action bar's menu?

Answer (score 0):

don't use a menu, use a custom view inside ActionBar
then you can have Images animated